# How to do a select without showing duplicate records (getting the id that will always be different)

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I need to get the last records that are not the same to put in last addresses.

However, to use the distinct I can't get the id_address,
can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: please give table defnition and sample data as text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've read your question twice and I still dont fully understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide an example of what the output should be? Also, can you share what you've tried to do already?

Comment: Maybe [group by](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) instead of DISTINCT?